# Sscanf delimiters for parsing

Tags: c, scanf

I want to parse /etc/passwd file using sscanf . Currently trying below snippet

```
        sscanf(buf,"%s:%*s:%*u:%*u:%*s:%*s",
               szName, &ncUser_gid);
```

its wrong. i need to parse only username and respective group Id of that user

Comment: You need to use scan sets `%[…]`, or more accurately `[^:]`, a negated scan set.

Comment: How exactly?? i'm bit confused Please help me

Comment: If you need general instructions on how to use the feature, there's a lot of documentation online for how `scanf` format strings work and scan sets. You should try Googling it. If you've read the documentation and have a specific question about a detailed point that you don't understand, then please clarify your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic answer is to use (negated) 'scan sets' — read the manual for [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html).

```
if (sscanf(buf, "%[^:]:%*[^:]:%*[^:]:%u", szName, &ncUser_gid) != 2)
```

This reads a sequence of non-colons into `szName`, and then skips a colon, the password field, a colon, the UID field, a colon, and reads the number in the next field into `ncUser_gid`.  It also checks that you got both values, while ignoring the other trailing fields (comment, home, shell).

Note that because you're using `sscanf()`, there really isn't a need to process any of the trailing fields.  Also, there are 7 fields, not 6, in a password file entry.  With `sscanf()`, this isn't a problem.  If you were reading from a file, it would be.  Also, if you were reading from a file, you'd have to worry about scan sets not skipping leading white space, which would be the newline left over from the previous line of input.  For file-stream parsing, you'd need to use:

```
int rc;
if ((rc = fscanf(fp, " %[^:]:%*[^:]:%u:%u:%[^:]:%[^:]:%[^:]",
                 username, &uid, &gid, comment, homedir, shell)) != 5 && rc != 6)
    …handle format error…
if (rc == 5)
    shell[0] = '\0';
```

Note that there does not have to be any data for the shell field.  This would run foul of an empty comment field, too, but that is normally populated.  Note that it skipped the password; it is seldom interesting in modern versions of Unix.

#### `sscanf()` example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[] = "root:*:0:1:System Administrator:/var/root:/bin/sh";

    char szName[10] = "Pygmalion";      // Make sure it isn't empty!;
    unsigned int ncUser_gid = 23456;    // Make sure it isn't zero!
    if (sscanf(buf, "%[^:]:%*[^:]:%*[^:]:%u", szName, &ncUser_gid) != 2)
        printf("Ooops!\n");
    else
        printf("User: [%s]; GID = %u\n", szName, ncUser_gid);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
User: [root]; GID = 1
```

(I hacked the entry so the UID and GID are different.)

#### `fscanf()` example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char passwd[] = "/etc/passwd";
    FILE *fp = fopen(passwd, "r");
    if (fp == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open '%s' for reading\n", passwd);
        return 1;
    }

    char username[64];
    unsigned uid;
    unsigned gid;
    char comment[64];
    char homedir[64];
    char shell[64];

    int rc;
    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        if ((rc = fscanf(fp, " %63[^:\n]:%*[^:\n]:%u:%u:%63[^:\n]:%63[^:\n]:%63[^:\n]",
                         username, &uid, &gid, comment, homedir, shell)) != 5 && rc != 6)
        {
            int c; 
            while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n')
                ;
        }
        else
        {
            if (rc == 5)
                shell[0] = '\0';
            printf("[%s] %u %u [%s] [%s] [%s]\n", username, uid, gid, comment, homedir, shell);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that on a Mac, the password file starts with a number of lines of `#` comments.  The `%[^:\n]` notation, or something similar, is required to avoid problems parsing that section of the file.  On sane systems without such comment lines in the file, you can probably get away without them.  Note too that the code protects itself from overflow in the string fields.

Also, I continued with `unsigned` integers for UID and GID, but `nobody` has a negative value `-2` for both UID and GID, so a signed type might be better.

Example output:

```
[nobody] 4294967294 4294967294 [Unprivileged User] [/var/empty] [/usr/bin/false]
[root] 0 0 [System Administrator] [/var/root] [/bin/sh]
[daemon] 1 1 [System Services] [/var/root] [/usr/bin/false]
…
```

All users have a specific shell specified on my Mac so the 'rc == 5' code hasn't really been tested.

Sample output:

```
[# Open Directory.
##
nobody] 4294967294 4294967294 [Unprivileged User] [/var/empty] [/usr/bin/false
```

JFTR: Tested on a Mac running macOS 10.12.5 using GCC 7.1.0.
Compilation command line like:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
> -Wstrict-prototypes pw89.c -o pw89
$
```

Comment: Getting garbage---->
"Netconf user: vbisalah22, respective group Id is: 976499253
Netconf user: vbisalah23, respective group Id is: 976564789"
But Group id for those users is 495

Comment: Fixed a typo in the UID scan set.  My compiler told me about my mistake.  Didn't yours tell you about my mistake?  If not, get a better compiler.